# Avoiding nullable FK - Database Design

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to figure out how to best represent my data  in my database with preferably no null FK(sql server).

I have a site where a user has to buy a membership(monthly subscription), can buy ads, buy credits to do more stuff on the site.

So I was thinking something like having these tables

```
Company
 -normal company columns
Plan 
  - Limitations (json, that contains all the limitations of what membership allows, ie can do x amount of seraches)
   - Name (ie Membership lv 1)
   - Price
   - Qty 
   - Unit (Monthly, Credit, etc)
PlanTypes
    - Type (membership, addon, ad)
CompanyPlans (junction table)
    - PlanId
    - CompanyId
    - Limitations (Json) - this would store like when their membership expires or how many credits they have left. If they would extend membership or buy credits the rows would be updated, so there would be business rules to basically make sure 1 row per plan per company, though this would not work really for ads as they can buy more than 1 ad.
Ads
 - normal add columns
 - Start
 - End
```

So my problem I run into is, that the `Plan table` is the table that keeps track of if their membership subscription, credits which I think is fine.

However when it gets to ads it gets weird, as right now I was planning to put the relationship with `Company`. So now all of sudden for ads the checking of if they are still active or not is done in the ads table where everything else is in the `CompanyPlan` table.

To make it worse does the start and end date of the ad still get duplicated in the `CompanyPlan` table for consistency?

I really don't want to try to break up the `Plan` table into something like Subscription Table, Addon table and Ad Table as I am planning to an `order history & order history line table` that links to the product bought and I don't want to have 3 different relationships to the Order history line table and have always 2 of FK relationships null, as I think that is bad as well.

Another option I was thinking but again I am not sure if it is bad practice is to put the Ad relationship on the `CompanyPlan Junction Table` and keep the start/end date in the `Company Table` and other info in the `Ad table.`

Example Data

```
Company

Id Name
1  My Compnay

PlanTypes
Id  Type
1  Membership
2  Addon
3  Ad


Plans

Id PlanTypeId Limitations Name Price Value Unit
1   1         {Searches: 100} Plan 1 $30  1  Month
2   2         {}              Extra Searches $10  100 Credits
3   3         {}              Ad1    $100  1   Month

CompanyPlan
Id  PlanId   Limitations CompnyId
1   1        {Start: "2018-01-01", End: {2018-02-01}, 1
2   2        {ExtraSearches: 100}, 1
3   3        {AdStart: "2018-01-01", AdEnd: {2018-02-01}, 1

Ads
Id CompanyId Start End
1  1         2018-01-01  2018-02-01

Order History
Id  CompanyId
1    1

Order Lines
Id   OrderHistoryId  PlanId
1      1              1
2      1              2
3      1              3
```

Comment: Let me get this straight. By `company` do you mean the client that buys ads?

Comment: Yes, "company" can be anyone, if it makes it easier to think of think of company as user, who can buy ad space on the site, must buy a membership and can buy addtional ad ons(lthat can do other things on the site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the start like The Impaler already mentioned in his comments, nullable FK aren't a bad thing if used correctly. I would design your tables as follow:

```
Company
-Id
-Name

Plan
-Id
-Name
-Details

Addon
-Id
-Value

DefaultPlanAddon
-Id
-Plan_Id
-Addon_Id

Subscription
-Id
-Company_Id
-Plan_Id
-Start
-End

SubscriptionAddons
-Id
-Subscription_Id
-Addon_Id

Advertisement
-Id
-Subscription_Id
-Content
-Start
-End
```

Most of the tables are pretty straight forward I guess.

**Company**

All data to indentify the company/customer.

**Plan**

Basic details about a plan.

**Addon**

Here it gets a bit more interesting. In this table are all addons saved. In my understanding addons are useable for all different plans. If this is not the case, you could add something like a *PlanAddons* table that holds the information which plans can have which addons. Value contains what this addon is about. Maybe about 100 extra adds or something other. As for what I know you can use a simple string as the type since a addon is basically an Id and a description of what this addon is.

**Subscription**

I would seperate make a subscription table. You can also save the start and end date for each subscription. With this you also have a pruchase history and dont need an *OrderHistory* table. If the start date does not equals the purchase date you can easily add a *PurchaseDate* column.

**SubscriptionAddon**

This table includes all addons for a specific subscription since one subcription can have many addons.

**DefaultPlanAddon**
This table stores the default addons for each plan. This informations are only used if a company buys a subscription. Your logic looks up what default addons a plan has and put int, together with other wanted addons, into the *SubscriptionAddon* table.

**Advertisement**

Here are all adds stored. Also with start and end. Like with a subscription you can use this table as well for the *OrderHistrory*.

Comment: Hi, I have to draw your design out and see how it works. With addons you are actually correct with both cases. Some addons are part of the "subscription" so you could buy a higher plan and it happens to have that addon plus other stuff, or you could buy a lower plan and then just buy that 1 addon you need.

Comment: Than I would still go with the SubscriptionAddon table. But in addition to a PlanAddon table that stores default addons for a plan.

Comment: What table would PlanAddons link to? In Plan table details would be a json stored?

Comment: A few things I don't get with your design is Addons: what does "value" hold? Where would the prices of the "Ads" live? A user bought 2 of the same addons(2 x 100 extra searches) does that mean 2 lines would go in subscription adds and I have to always add all lines together to compare against? Finally What would Order History / Order History lines look like?

Comment: Look my edits. With that design you would not need history tables. If you need financical data seperated from your "normal" data, that is another story.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, maybe order history is not a good name, basically I need a purchase history, Every month they get billed, 1 month could be for  1 Plan, 2 Addons, 5 Ads. I need basicly an invoice generated.With that info and price

Comment: Though I am liking this design, I still feel like something is missing, Say they bought 2 of the same addon of 100 extra adds. Now they got 200 extra adds total, they ad a new item. Now I got to go and calculate every addon of that type to get total and then compare, fine for now, but every addon will make that lookup slower, should I have a calculation table?

Comment: In my opinion you dont need an order history. All needed information are available. You can add a cost column to the subscription table (and the advertisement table if they have additional costs). And yes, you can calculate the total costs. Database systems are pretty fast with such stuff. You could use a view in sql server for example.

Comment: hmm, I still thinking I do for a couple reasons, 1) dealing with companies  and they want to see some sort of invoice that is addressed to them with order numbers that can be checked back later 2) company audits or even internal will want to see when and what was purchased on any given month.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your case, this is what I think:

- I think the advertisement table (ads) should store the begin/end date of the ad.
- The relationship between `company` and `ads` is 1:n. So `ads` has a foreign key pointing to `company`.
- The company table should not store the begin/end date of the ad, since the same company could buy more ads in the future. When it does, the new ad gets a begin/end date, without affecting the old ad, that may be obsolete at this point.

This should keep you model clean, without (dangerous) redundancy.

Comment: Yea, I keep thinking this as well that ad should not be part of the CompanyPlan table, but does that mean it should not be at all part of the Plan table as well? How would Order History look then if they are sepreated? I user could buy an ad and memberhip at the same time.

Comment: As far as I understand (I may have gotten it wrong) **plans** are separate from **ads**, aren't they? A company can buy only a plan, only an ad, or both at the same time. If this is the case, then they should be stored in separate tables. The order history can have two nullable foreign keys: one pointing to plan, and the other one pointing to ad; only one can be null (you can enforce this with a constraint).

Comment: Yes, they can only have 1 active plan at a time, though they can buy as many addons as they like, like buy 10,000 more searches (right now part of the Plan table), or they can buy as many ads as they like. I was not sure if have null FK is good practice or not. Also bit worried about the order table having tons of nullable FK in the future as eventually I will need to have a model for pay per click on a different part of the site, ie there are going to be ton of different revenue models that could all be billed through the same order.

Comment: Don't worry about nullables FKs. That's a pretty standard practice (when it makes business model sense, of course). Databases are pretty good at that. Make sure you add the corresponding constraint so at least one of them should have a value.

Comment: Ok, Can these constraints be send via code first EF?  Also do you think the addons should be separated out as well(which might have to be a many to many, though some of the addons are like searches where they  go down). This would mean I would have a plan table, ad table and addon table.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about EF. And yes, I think the addons should be separated. The mantra is "keep a clean model that will be able to respond any query in a simple way". If you merge tables the wrong way just to save space or other reason, you'll regret it badly in the future.

Comment: Ok no worries, I will look into EF later, How would you track addons that are number based(ie x amount of searches) to see if they have not hit that limit and addons that maybe subscription based(ie you can see this page for x days).